# How to find name of the gene

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, database, gene, data

Considering the [kegg](http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?etr:ETAE_0074) page, this page contains the description of the gene Edwardsiella tarda EIB202: ETAE_0074 . Now this gene has a name given in the page as : wabG.

Now considering another [gene 1](http://bacteria.ensembl.org/vibrio_cholerae_4260b/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=VC4260B_11320;r=174.VC4260B.1_11:11248-12258;t=ELP50774) and [gene 2](http://bacteria.ensembl.org/vibrio_cholerae_4260b/Gene/Summary?g=VC4260B_02250;r=174.VC4260B.1_3:67833-69557;t=ELP51673;db=core) , what is the name of these genes? How to I find the name of these gene and from which website?

Comment: The gene (gene-2) name **is** VC4260B_02250. Many microbial genes are named like that (like MTB with RVxxx). You can try downloading the genome annotation file for this species. It may have alternative names and ENSEMBL/Refseq ids.

Comment: then what is wabG

Comment: That is from a different species altogether.

Comment: i understand, but wont names be present?? like wabG??